# Axios post form data with user id of Logged in user

Tags: reactjs, axios, postman, laravel-7, laravel-api

i want to post  my form data using axios.post with the current user login id.

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/add-property/', 
      formData, {
        headers:{
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://http://127.0.0.1:8000',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
        }
      }
    ).then(function(response){ 
      console.log(response.data.message)
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error)
    });
```

kindly tell me about these things ?

1. what should be the api url to add some data with the id of logged in user ?
2. how to get the current logged in user id ?

my backend is in laravel  and my store function controller is something like this :-

```
public function AddProperty(Request $request, $id) {
    
    
        
        $validator                     =       Validator::make($request->all(),
            [
                "agency_name"                       =>  "required",
                "agency_location"                   =>  "required",
                // my rest of validations
          
            ]               
        );

        if($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(["status" => "failed", "validation_errors" => $validator- 
            >errors()]);
        }


        //--------------------get user id---------------------------------------------------
        $user                    =       array();

        $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->first();
        
        $user_identification     =       $user->id;

        
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        $agency_name                            =   $request->input('agency_name');
        $agency_location                        =   $request->input('agency_location');

        $user_id                                =   $user_identification;
        
        $propertyArray = array(
            'agency_name'                       => "$agency_name",
            'agency_location'                   => "$agency_location",

            'user_id'                           =>  $user_identification
        );
       
        $property        =       AddProperty::create($propertyArray);
        return "property added succesfully with id:".$property->id;
```

my route for add property is :-

```
Route::post("add-property/{id}", "AddPropertyController@AddProperty");
```

when i pass id  from postman it enters data into the database  i am confused with how to get  the id from the react and pass it in the post api and the enter the data in my db.

kindly someone help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel authentication you can simply call

```php
$user = Auth::user();
```

to retrieve the authenticated user

If you are not using the laravel authentication, well it depends on how you implemented that

Comment: no i have not  used laravel authentication. i have made my simple login and register in react and posted this data through user controller.

Comment: Well than we can't know how to retrieve the user id, it depends on how you store it.... I would suggest you to use laravel authentication if you are not familiar with user authentication

Answer (score 0):

Save the logged in user object or the auth(bearer token) in the local storage of the browser.

Then when sending with the post api simply use that token or user id in the header of your api.

You can use the local storage solution like this:

```
var userObj= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userObj'));
```

Or you can use react js props solution in `componentWillReceiveProps` get the logged in user.